# How to only show the times that are required on secondstotime

Tags: php, function, time, seconds

I currently have this function running to show the time by days, hours minutes etc.
However I want to go from the code below to only showing the days, hours & minutes if they are above 1, otherwise to not show it.

```
function secondsToTime($seconds) {
    $dtF = new DateTime("@0");
    $dtT = new DateTime("@$seconds");
    return $dtF->diff($dtT)->format('%a days, %h hours, %i minutes and %s seconds');
}
```